# Grab product code from a url, do I need regex for this?

Tags: python, regex

A url looks like:

```
http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/blahblah?&PC=abd23423&uy=020
```

I need to extract the value:  `abc23423`

I tried this regex but its not working:

```
rx = re.compile(r'PC=(\w*)&uy=')
```

I then I did:

```
pc = rx.search(url).groups()
```

but I get an error:

attribute error:  nonetype object has no attribute groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Sheesh. What was I thinking?

```
import urlparse
u = 'http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/blahblah?&PC=abd23423&uy=020'
query = urlparse.urlparse(u).query
urlparse.parse_qs(query) # {'PC': ['abd23423'], 'uy': ['020']}
```

**Original Answer**

This code snippet worked for me. Take a look:

```
import urlparse, re

u = 'http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/blahblah?&PC=abd23423&uy=020'
query = urlparse.urlparse(u).query

pattern = re.compile('PC=(\w*)&uy')
pattern.findall(query) # ['abd23423']
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html).

Comment: i tried: urlparse(url).query and then passing that to urlparse.parse_qs but it says there is no function parse_qs  do I have an old version?

Comment: Strange. I am using v2.6.2 (on Ubuntu Jaunty) and `urlparse` has a `parse_qs` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
lol = "http://www.example.com/cgi-bin/blahblah?&PC=abd23423&uy=020"
s = re.compile("&PC=(\w+)&uy=")
g = s.search(lol)
g.groups()
('abd23423',)
```

This seems to work for me.